# use shell-escape output with newlines in pgfplots/tikz

Tags: line-breaking, shell-escape

The following example works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table{
0 0 
0.5 0.25
1 1
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, I cannot take the data from an external program. As a simulation let us say that

```
printf '0 0\n0.5 0.25\n1 1\n'
```

prints the desired

```
0 0
0.5 0.25
1 1
```

Now I would like to write instead

```
\addplot table{
\input|"printf '0 0\n0.5 0.25\n1 1'"
};
```

and compile it with `pdflatex --shell-escape`. I am quite sure that the newlines are the problem and catcode tables may be a solution but I was not able to find an appropriate solution.

Update:
`\string\n` and expandable input via `@@\input` were suggested similar to something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\makeatletter
\let\zz\@@input
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table{
\zz|"printf '0 0\string\n0.5 0.25\string\n1 1'"
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I think, I have tried all variations with `\zz`,`\input`,`\n`, `\string\n`, `\string\n\string\n` and none of them worked.

Comment: probably you want `\string\n` but it depends on whether you need another layer of quoting for the `\ ` on your command shell, it is system dependent, but you need `\string\n` or it tries to expand the undefined tex command `\n`, but it could be you need `\string\\n` instead:-)

Comment: Your suggestion works outside a tikzpicture but unfortunately not inside a tikzpicture. (Doubling `\string\n`did not work either, inputting with an expandable input did not work either.)

Comment: can you use a normal file input at that point or does the argument of `\addplot table` need to _expand_ to its content (in which case you would need ``\@@input` not `\input` (and make @ a letter with \makeatletter )

Comment: I would like to solve this problem without needing to write and read an extra file. I have updated the question (`\@@input` did not yet solve the problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Christian Feuersänger (the author of pgfplots), everything inside `addplot{}` is not expandable. Hence, a solution with the given conditions is not possible.